# XUnit Debugging Fails in Resharper

Tags: resharper, xunit

I've got a new project with XUnit tests, and they'll run just fine in Resharper's test runner. However, when I try to debug one of those tests, I get an error:

"Cannot launch debugger. Error Code: 897100016. Error Message: 0. Error Info: 0"

Also, the error message sometimes changes from 0 to 198255

After this error, the test runner hangs in a pending state until I manually quit the test run.

I've added "Debugger.Launch();" to the XUnit test, and there is no change. I've also updated my target references in the JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR4xxx config files, though that seems to have been an error with Resharper 5 builds.

I've created the same test in NUnit, and debugging works fine.

I've got VS2015 and Resharper Ultimate installed, running XUnit 2.20. Target framework is 4.6.

Comment: Sounds like a defect of ReSharper which you should contact JetBrains.